# Appending parameter to commented-out iframe src

Tags: jquery, iframe

I have a page with a large list of videos on it, so I'm using thumbnails that uncomment the actual video embed code when clicked (to speed up load time).

To avoid needing two clicks to play a video, those iframe videos must autoplay. So I also need to append a `&autoplay=1` parameter to all iframe src's.

Here is the code I have so far, but I don't know how to select commented elements:

```
$(function() {
   $("iframe").attr('src', function(i, h) {
      return h + (h.indexOf('?') != -1 ? "&autoplay=1" : "?autoplay=1");
   });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better way might be to store the embed code in the js, and use that to populate the video area. The links to the videos can be in the dom like normal. Something like this:

```
 function makeEmbed(link){
      return '<embed part1>' + link + '</embed part2 including autoplay>';
 }

 $('a.videolink').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var newEmbed = makeEmbed( $(this).attr('href') );
      append(newEmbed);
 });
```

Comment: the other advantage here is that if js is turned off, the buttons will link out to the video.

Answer (score 1):

Comments are just that, comments, not elements. Can't be manipulated. What you'll probably want to do is hide the videos and unhide them.

Comment: That would defeat the purpose of doing this to avoid a long load time. I know for a fact that commented elements can be manipulated. It's just not as easy as using a selector...

Comment: Well, by default I don't think you can do that unless you use something like http://chivil.com/uncomment/. But IMO, commenting and uncommenting elements for your purpose, I don't think is right way to go.

Comment: Why don't you just store the videos' urls that you don't what to show in an variable and then append the iframes to the DOM whenever you want by extracting those values? That won't affect performance and it's a more feasible way to do it.